# Regex to Identify Month from the first 3 letter

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a date format of

`12March2018`

I am trying to get a regular expression to identify the pattern using a regex expression. 1st letter must be numeric.Followed by the first 3 letters of the month. If the word which follows the numeric matches with any first 3 letter of any month it should return true. How do I get it?

Comment: I think you should consider checking both (1st letter = numeric + next 3 letters represent month) and (1st letter and 2nd letter = numeric + next 3 letters represent month)

Comment: how to check the letters representing the months

Comment: You said first letter must be numeric. But don't you mean that the string should start with a number?

Comment: Also, do you need the regex code in Java, Python, Javascript or what?

Comment: Ya the string should start with a number. I want the regex code for Javascript. @CoffeehouseCoder

Comment: Why not capture groups using `(\d+)(\w+)(\d+)` and then use *code* to clearly express your logic rather than a 500 foot (and 6 inches) long regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try using this regex:

```
/(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)/g
```

In your case for identifying `March` from `12March2018`, you can use as:

```
(?:Mar(?:ch))
```

Here `(?:Mar)` is for identifying a month which is denote by 3 character (simple representation). And by using `(?:ch)`, the full name of the month is matched or identified from string.

You can test this [here](https://regex101.com/r/wXIMo7/6).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna match groups of months, say, those with 31-days, with all input being first 3 letters, properly cased, here's the most succinct regex I could conjure up to match all 7 of months using just 4 letters :

> ```
> {m,g,n}awk '/[acgl]/'
> ```

```
Jan    J [a] n
Mar    M [a] r
May    M [a] y
Jul    J  u [l]
Aug    A  u [g]
Oct    O [c] t
Dec    D [c] t
```

if they're already all lowercased, then

> ```
> /[^a]a|[cgl]/
> /a[^p]|[cgl]/
> ```

```
jan
mar
may
jul
aug
oct
dec
```

for the 30-day ones, regardless of proper or lowercase,

> ```
> /p|v|un/
> ```

```
apr      a [p] r
jun      j [u][n]
sep      s  e [p]
nov      n  o [v]
```

if you wanna match what people frequently describe as then "**summer months**", despite that not being officially defined :

> ```
> /u/
> ```

```
Jun    J [u] n
Jul    J [u] l
Aug    A [u] g
```

just the 4th-quarter months :

> ```
> /[cv]/
> ```

```
Oct
Nov
Dec
```

depending on whether you want to maximize the amount of months captured, or require uniqueness, here's a quick reference table as to uniqueness of the first 3 letters, when properly cased :

```
 repeated : unique   DFNOS bglotvy
 repeated : 2-times     AM cnpr
 repeated : 3-times      J aeu
```

when they're all uni-cased :

```
 repeated : unique  BDFGLSTVY repeated : 3-times EJNU
 repeated : 2-times CMOPR     repeated : 5-times A
```

when you include every letter of their full english names, uni-cased:

```
 repeated : unique    FGHIV   repeated : 6-times   U
 repeated : 2-times   DLPS    repeated : 8-times   A
 repeated : 3-times   CJOT    repeated : 9-times   R
 repeated : 4-times   NY      repeated : 11-times  E
 repeated : 5-times   BM
```